# Finding optimum CPU limit for docker containers in Splunk

Tags: docker, containers, cpu, splunk

I'm using Splunk to monitor my applications.

I also store resource statistics in my Splunk too.

Goal: I want to find the optimum CPU limit for each container.
How to I write a query that finds an optimum CPU limit? Or the other question is Should I?

Concern1: When I start customizing my query and let's say that I have used MAX(CPU) command. It doesn't mean that my container will be running at level most of the time. So, I might set an unnecessary high limit for my containers.

Let me explain, when I find a CPU limit value via MAX(CPU) command as 10, this top value might be happened because of a bulk operation. So, my container's expected resource may be around 1.2 all the time, except this single 1 operation that one. So, using MAX value won't work.

Concern2: Let's say that I have used the value of AVG(CPU) value and used it. And that is 2, So how many of my operations will be waited for how many minutes after this change? Or how many of them are going to be timed out? It may create a lot of side-effects. How will I decide the real average value? What parameters should be used?

Is it possible to include such conditions in the query? Or do I need an AI to decide it? :)

Here are my givin parameters:

```
path=statistics.cpus_system_time_secs
path=statistics.cpus_user_time_secs
path=statistics.cpus_nr_periods
path=statistics.cpus_nr_throttled
path=statistics.cpus_throttled_time_secs
path=statistics.cpus_limit
```

I bet you can ask better questions than me. Let's discuss.

Answer (score 0):

"Optimum" is going to depend *greatly* on your own environment (resources available, application priority, etc)

You probably want to look at a combination of the following factors:

- avg(CPU)
- max(CPU) (and time spent there)
- min(CPU) (and time spent there)

I *suspect* your "optimum" limit is going to be a % below your max...but only if you're spending 'a lot' of time maxxed-out

And, of course, being "maxed" may not matter, if other containers are running acceptably

Keep in mind, once you set that limit, your max will drop (as, likely, will your avg)